# Microsoft Flow emails members of an Office 365 group prematurely when a news post is added in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365, power-automate

A Microsoft Flow that emails Office 365 group members when a news post is added to a SharePoint team site triggers successfully. However, the email is sent before the author clicks "Post News." The email sent has no contents. My guess is that some sort of autosave operation happens in the background, adding a file to `/SitePages` (and thereby triggering the Flow) before the author is finished. Has anyone encountered this? While Googling, I saw several recommendations to use MS Flows for sending members email notifications when new posts are added, but none mentioned this issue.

The reason for using MS Flow instead of built-in SharePoint functionality is (1) it appears neither being a group member nor "following" a site triggers email notifications, (2) I don't have admin privileges to set up site alerts, (3) based on the nature of the authors, we don't believe authors will remember to click "Send by email" (and we don't want to manually monitor that), and (4) based on the nature of our user base, we doubt most users will take the time to configure their SharePoint notifications.

Thank you if anyone has expertise to share.

(MS Flow below - even if the Flow is inaccurate, it is still triggered right after an author initiates a new blog post and before the author clicks "Post News.")

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the file is created once the author starts working on the news. You have several options to work with that. Here are some suggestions:

- Build a [delay](https://veenstra.me.uk/2019/05/15/microsoft-flow-sometimes-you-just-have-to-wait/) after the trigger and wait, for example an hour, until you continue the flow and send the e-mail.
- Instead of just a delay, you could also loop with a delay and check the last change date and send the e-mail only if the last edit is a specific time ago.
- You can also think about building some kind of "newsletter" to send only a daily e-mail with all new news-items to reduce e-mail-clutter.

Comment: Thank you @Gerrit